# Sending Underscore to a Serial Port in Perl

Tags: perl, encoding, serial-port

When I send an underscore to the Serial Port (COM42), it acts as though I've send a backspace to the Serial Port.
For example, if I send "Perl_Great", my Serial Port displays "PerGreat"
I currently have the Serial Port configured this way.
Is there a parameter to configure the Serial Port to a different encoding such that it won't treat an underscore as a backspace?

```
use Win32::SerialPort;
my $port = new Win32::SerialPort( "\\\\.\\" . $self->{Port} )
        or $self->__Error( "Could not open com port $self->{Port}\n\t$^E\n", 'FATAL' );

$port->baudrate($self->{BaudRate});
$port->parity($self->{Parity});
$port->databits($self->{DataBits});
$port->stopbits($self->{StopBits});
$port->handshake( "none" );
$port->are_match( "\r" );     # the symbol that "lookfor" will be looking for in a blocking call
$port->read_const_time(2000); #timeout for blocking read (ms)
$port->lookclear;

$port->write_settings();

my $command = "Perl_Great";
$port->write($command);  # where $command is previously loaded with "Perl_Great".  I checked with a Win32::MsgBox That the string is intact at this point
```

Comment: what is the serial port connected to and/or how are you seeing what is received from the serial port?

Comment: We have a simple terminal style program on the other side of a virtual port connection.  In our case, the virtual connection is COM52.  On the terminal, the display indicates that the underscore is acting as a backspace, and the response from the program indicates the same (Invalid Parameter Error)

Comment: I'm finding the description very confusing. Please describe the full setup. In particular, show the full treatment of sending "Perl_Great". For example "the perl program running on host A programmatically sends the "Perl_Great" set of characters to the the local COM42 virtual device, which is set up to route those characters over the network where they're received by host B. A terminal program running on host B sees those characters as a reply from the server it thinks it acting as a terminal to, but displays 'PerGreat'. Somehow something also displays Invalid Character error?"

Comment: I do apologise, I only have control of part of the setup, and I've inherited most of the code.  
We have another Script Engine in VB that can successfully send the Underscore through the serial port to the terminal.

The setup involves my scripting engine is using COM42.
Through a Network Serial Port Kit Tool, we have COM42 communicating with COM52.
The Terminal on the other side is in control of COM52.
This is all on a single PC.

The text I send through the Perl Script is displayed in the Terminal Window.

Comment: The code that is used down the road to put the string onto the COM port is:
 '$port->write($command);  # where $command is previously loaded with "Perl_Great".  I checked with a Win32::MsgBox That the string is intact at this point'

I was thinking that it was an encoding problem (the VB engine uses UTF8), or there are some predefined control characters, and Underscore happens to be one of them.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to you question is - "probably not" :-)

Your question "Is there a parameter to configure the Serial Port to a different encoding such that it won't treat an underscore as a backspace?", might be better phrased, as "what is causing the receiver of the string "Perl_Great" to drop two characters and only get  "PerGreat"?

You ask about encoding, and mention UTF8, have you verified that your [underscore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underscore) in "Perl_Great" is eq "\x5f", and not some magic utf-8 string